Javascript Nested JSON get parent results from child
I have a nested JSON and I'm getting the "variants" results from API. And I'm trying to get this variants parent names.
Here is the json:
{
    "active": true,
    "main": [{
        "name": "groupOne",
        "heights": [{
                "name": "sm",
                "active": true,
                "addSelectedProduct": false,
                "colors": [{
                            "name": "gold",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11111"], "variants": ["11112"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "blue",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11113"], "variants": ["11114"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "white",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11115"], "variants": ["11116"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "black",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11117"], "variants": ["11118"]
                            }
                        }
                ]
                        
            },
            {
                "name": "md",
                "active": true,
                "addSelectedProduct": false,
                "colors": [{
                            "name": "gold",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11119"], "variants": ["11121"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "blue",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11122"], "variants": ["11123"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "white",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11124"], "variants": ["11125"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "black",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11126"], "variants": ["11127"]
                            }
                        }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "lg",
                "active": true,
                "addSelectedProduct": false,
                "colors": [{
                            "name": "gold",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11128"], "variants": ["11129"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "blue",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11131"], "variants": ["11132"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "white",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11133"], "variants": ["11134"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "black",
                            "triggers": {
                                "offerIds": ["11135"], "variants": ["11136"]
                            }
                        }
                ]
            }]

        },
        {
        "name": "groupTwo",
        "heights": [{
            "name": "sm",
            "active": true,
            "addSelectedProduct": false,
            "colors": [{
                        "name": "gold",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11137"], "variants": ["11138"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "blue",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11139"], "variants": ["11141"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "white",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11142"], "variants": ["11143"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "black",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11144"], "variants": ["11145"]
                        }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "md",
            "active": true,
            "addSelectedProduct": false,
            "colors": [{
                        "name": "gold",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11146"], "variants": ["11147"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "blue",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11148"], "variants": ["11149"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "white",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11151"], "variants": ["11152"]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "name": "black",
                        "triggers": {
                            "offerIds": ["11153"], "variants": ["11154"]
                        }
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "name": "lg",
            "active": true,
            "addSelectedProduct": false,
            "colors": [{
                "name": "gold",
                "triggers": {
                        "offerIds": ["11155"], "variants": ["11156"]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "blue",
                "triggers": {
                        "offerIds": ["11157"], "variants": ["11158"]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "white",
                "triggers": {
                        "offerIds": ["11159"], "variants": ["11159"]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "black",
                "triggers": {
                        "offerIds": ["11161"], "variants": ["11162"]
                }
            }
        ]
        }]


    }]

}

I tried a lot of ways like filter, indexOf but no luck. I can reach the final step with nested foreach functions like that:
var elMain, elHeights, elColor, elOffer;

function findProduct(item) {
    app.main.forEach(function(el) {
        el.heights.forEach(function(itemHeights) {
            itemHeights.colors.forEach(function(itemColor) {
                if(itemColor.triggers.variants.indexOf(item.toString())) {
                    elOffer = itemColor.triggers.offerIds
                    elColor = itemColor;
                    elHeights = itemHeights;
                    elMain = el;
                } else{
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

findProduct(11123)

console.log(elMain);
console.log(elHeights);
console.log(elColor);
console.log(elOffer);

But I can't get the correct result. I need to get selected variant's parent names directly. Is there a method for that? Any help would be awesome.

What are the expected results? For what it's worth, that's not JSON, but a Javascript Object. JSON is a formatted string.

@mykaf Yes, that's correct. I just have "variants" value and trying to get "name" values of parents. But no luck.

Do you see the name property for each item you are logging?

If indexOf doesn't find the value, it returns -1 which is truthy, if the value is the first item, it returns 0, which is falsey.

You don't have to do all that. You can just do
const products = functionThatGetsDataFromAPI();
const key = "11123";
const groups = products.main;
var variant = null;

groups.every((group) => {
    return group.heights.every((height) => {
        return height.colors.every((color)=>{
            if (color.triggers.variants.includes(key)) {
                variant=height.name;
            }
            return !variant; // Exit the loop if the variant is found
        });
    });
});
console.log(variant)

This will exit early if found instead of having to loop through every object every time like the forEach does

You shouldn't use forEach because it doesn't let you break easily from it when you have found your match. Better use a for (key in obj).
With forEach


var app={active:!0,main:[{name:"groupOne",heights:[{name:"sm",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11111"],variants:["11112"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11113"],variants:["11114"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11115"],variants:["11116"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11117"],variants:["11118"]}}]},{name:"md",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11119"],variants:["11121"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11122"],variants:["11123"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11124"],variants:["11125"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11126"],variants:["11127"]}}]},{name:"lg",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11128"],variants:["11129"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11131"],variants:["11132"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11133"],variants:["11134"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11135"],variants:["11136"]}}]}]},{name:"groupTwo",heights:[{name:"sm",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11137"],variants:["11138"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11139"],variants:["11141"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11142"],variants:["11143"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11144"],variants:["11145"]}}]},{name:"md",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11146"],variants:["11147"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11148"],variants:["11149"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11151"],variants:["11152"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11153"],variants:["11154"]}}]},{name:"lg",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11155"],variants:["11156"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11157"],variants:["11158"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11159"],variants:["11159"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11161"],variants:["11162"]}}]}]}]};


var elMain, elHeights, elColor, elOffer;

function findProduct(item) {
  found = false
  app.main.forEach(function(el) {
    if (found) return;
    elMain = el.name
    el.heights.forEach(function(itemHeights) {
      if (found) return;
      elHeights = itemHeights.name
      itemHeights.colors.forEach(function(itemColor) {
        if (found) return;
        elColor = itemColor.name
        if (itemColor.triggers.variants.indexOf("" + item) >= 0) {
          elOffer = itemColor.triggers.offerIds
          found = true
        }
      })
    })
  })
}

findProduct(11123)

console.log(elMain);
console.log(elHeights);
console.log(elColor);
console.log(elOffer);
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}



With for in


var app={active:!0,main:[{name:"groupOne",heights:[{name:"sm",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11111"],variants:["11112"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11113"],variants:["11114"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11115"],variants:["11116"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11117"],variants:["11118"]}}]},{name:"md",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11119"],variants:["11121"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11122"],variants:["11123"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11124"],variants:["11125"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11126"],variants:["11127"]}}]},{name:"lg",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11128"],variants:["11129"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11131"],variants:["11132"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11133"],variants:["11134"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11135"],variants:["11136"]}}]}]},{name:"groupTwo",heights:[{name:"sm",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11137"],variants:["11138"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11139"],variants:["11141"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11142"],variants:["11143"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11144"],variants:["11145"]}}]},{name:"md",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11146"],variants:["11147"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11148"],variants:["11149"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11151"],variants:["11152"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11153"],variants:["11154"]}}]},{name:"lg",active:!0,addSelectedProduct:!1,colors:[{name:"gold",triggers:{offerIds:["11155"],variants:["11156"]}},{name:"blue",triggers:{offerIds:["11157"],variants:["11158"]}},{name:"white",triggers:{offerIds:["11159"],variants:["11159"]}},{name:"black",triggers:{offerIds:["11161"],variants:["11162"]}}]}]}]};

var elMain, elHeights, elColor, elOffer;

function findProduct(item) {
  found = false
  for (var i in app.main) {
    el = app.main[i]
    elMain = el.name
    for (var j in el.heights) {
      itemHeights = el.heights[j]
      elHeights = itemHeights.name
      for (var k in itemHeights.colors) {
        itemColor = itemHeights.colors[k]
        elColor = itemColor.name
        if (itemColor.triggers.variants.indexOf("" + item) >= 0) {
          elOffer = itemColor.triggers.offerIds
          return
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

findProduct(11123)

console.log(elMain);
console.log(elHeights);
console.log(elColor);
console.log(elOffer);
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}



